# How can I make ETL from code?

Tags: ravendb, etl

I would like to run ETL transformation during my deployment - from current database to transformed and then swap transformed db to current, for ex. when I have to change my documents structure.
Is there any api to do this from the code?

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/studio/overview/settings/etl

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/studio/overview/settings/etl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ETL configuration is saved as a replication destination.
You can save the document on the new db from the old one, and it will work